# declaring Iterator<? extends E & Comparable<? super E>> iterator in java

Tags: java

Can I declare the following in Java?

```
public class NewIterator<E extends Comparable<? super E>> implements Iterator<E> {
    NewIterator(Iterator<? extends E & Comparable<? super E>> iterator){
        ...
    }
```

I am getting an error saying

```
Multiple markers at this line
    - Incorrect number of arguments for type Iterator<E>; it cannot be parameterized with arguments <? extends E, Comparable<? super E>>
    - Syntax error on token ",", ; expected
    - Syntax error on token "&", , expected
    - Syntax error on token ")", ; expected
```

Comment: The compiler is shooting you down...so I'd say "no".  Could you elaborate on why you need this generified in this way, or rather, what generification you're attempting to perform?

Comment: Just use `Iterator<? extends E>`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

By defining your class as

```
class NewIterator<E extends Comparable<? super E>> implements Iterator<E> {
```

you say that `E` has to implement `Comparable<? super E>`.

Now in the constructor you try to repeat that and allow subtypes of E.

```
NewIterator(Iterator<? extends E & Comparable<? super E>> iterator){
    ...
}
```

If you do just

```
public NewIterator(Iterator<? extends E> iterator) {

}
```

You should get what you want because `E` already defines that it's a type that implements the comparable interface.

Example

```
class IntegerNumber {}

class PositiveNumber extends IntegerNumber implements Comparable<IntegerNumber> {}

class OddPositiveNumber extends PositiveNumber {}

private NewIterator<PositiveNumber> newIterator;
void foo() {
    Iterator<PositiveNumber> iterator = createIteratorFrom(
        new PositiveNumber(1),
        new OddPositiveNumber(7)
    );
    this.newIterator = new NewIterator(iterator);
}
```

If you use `PositiveNumber` in `NewIterator<E extends Comparable<? super E>>` you can replace `E` by `PositiveNumber`. So your constructor accepts `Iterator<? extends PositiveNumber>`. You can now create an iterator over any subclass of `PositiveNumber` but since that class inherits from `PositiveNumber` it must also inherit the `Comparable<IntegerNumber>` interface.